# EPUB in Protege

Tags: epub, owl, protege

How can i represent an **EPUB** property in **Protege**?

I need to set it with the content of an **EPUB** file, so I can infer some metadata about the individuals of my ontology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on your individuals. According to the epub community, the following example is the minimal set that all the publications must contain:

```
<package … unique-identifier="pub-id">
…
<metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
    <dc:identifier id="pub-id">urn:uuid:A1B0D67E-2E81-4DF5-9E67-A64CBE366809</dc:identifier>
    <dc:title>Norwegian Wood</dc:title>
    <dc:language>en</dc:language>
    <meta property="dcterms:modified">2011-01-01T12:00:00Z</meta>
</metadata>
…
```

So, based on this example, I would say you need to minimum have:

```
hasUUID
hasTitle
hasLanguage
```

Also, depending on your system, they could either be object property or datatype property.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I'm searching and I need to know how it is possible to automatize the reasoning process of getting these minimum metadata and infer incomplete metadata. For example, infer the author of a book given the content of the book and other metadata. I just don't know how to do it!

Comment: Isn't it better to create your full set and enforce a minimal set based on the full set? I mean for example you have 20 properties of which you need 5 to be enforced. You can define property restriction with the use of "min". For example, Book hasAuthor min 1 Author. Does this help?